# How to calculate sum of value for 4 type radio button in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I have some problem about calculation using js. Here my interface.

[image]

if i click button Yes, value=1, else it is value=0 and the total will displayed in sub_total. However, i have some problem how to create javascript for this calculation. Here my html code.

```
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_3',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_3',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_4',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_4',1,null) !!}</td>
```

This is my javascript.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('mcr').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.name === 'que_1' || event.target.name === 'que_2' || event.target.name === 'que_3' || event.target.name === 'que_4') {
        var item1 = 0,
                item2 = 0,
                item3 = 0,
                item4 = 0,
                totalPrice = 0,
                items1 = document.getElementsByName('que_1'),
                items2 = document.getElementsByName('que_2'),
                items3 = document.getElementsByName('que_3'),
                items4 = document.getElementsByName('que_4');

        //at here, how can i calculate for que3 and que4
        if (event.target.name === 'que_1') {
            item1 = parseInt(event.target.value);

            for (i = 0; i < items2.length; i++) {
                if (items2[i].checked) {
                    item2 = parseInt(items2[i].value);
                }
            }
        }

        if (event.target.name === 'que_2') {
            for (i = 0; i < items1.length; i++) {
                if (items1[i].checked) {
                    item1 = parseInt(items1[i].value);
                }
            }
            item2 = parseInt(event.target.value);
        }

        totalPrice = item1 + item2;
        $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: You have HTML and JavaScript code, but you have taged PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since values are `1` and `0` can just get length of collection of checked radios that have `1` as value

```js
var $radios = $(':radio[name^="que_"]').change(function() {

  var totalPrice = $radios.filter(function() {
    return this.checked && this.value === '1'
  }).length;

  $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);

});

// change first one on page load for demo
$radios.first().change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>No
    <input type="radio" name="que_1" value="0">
  </label>
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="que_1" value="1" checked>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>No
    <input type="radio" name="que_2" value="0">
  </label>
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="que_2" value="1" checked>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>No
    <input type="radio" name="que_3" value="0" checked>
  </label>
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="que_3" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>No
    <input type="radio" name="que_4" value="0">
  </label>
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="que_4" value="1" checked>
  </label>
</div>

<h4>Total: <input id="sub_total" value=0></h4>
```

Comment: I've been try and its working. How about in subtotal have an operation, after radio button count the number of value 1, in subtotal will convert to operation value. Example: sub_total /4 * 30% = ____%. How js will be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by jQuery! Catch radio button click and loop all radio button and check each radio has checked by `prop('checked')` . I think you only want to add price in total if radio value is `1` so put the condition for that with `&` operator .

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function() {
    var totalPrice = 0;
   $("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
       var cur_val = parseInt($(this).val())
       if($(this).prop("checked") && cur_val) { // is checked and is value 1
           totalPrice += cur_val;
       }
   });
    $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to catch only those radio buttons that are clicked and do a sum of values. So here is the simplest way to do in JQuery:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    totalPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
});
```